# sfValidatorDoctrineUnique in an update/edit context

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'm using a form class in two separate contexts: both to create a new record and also to edit that record. I've set up a post-validator as follows to check that the URL field is unique.

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorAnd(array(
   new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array('model' => 'Page', 'column' => array('url')), array('invalid' => 'This URL already exists.'))
)));
```

The validator works great when I'm creating a new record. However, when editing an existing record, it throws an error because it detects itself as a duplicate. In other words, if I edit the record but make no changes to the URL, it throws a duplicate error.

This must be a common issue so I'm wondering what the Symfony way of dealing with this would be? Basically I'd like it to ignore itself when saving (no duplicate exists) but still run the post-validator to ensure no true duplicates exist.

Comment: tom, please let me know the solution you found, as i am having the same problem. thanks.

Comment: my solution found: first parameter to sfValidatorDoctrineUnique should have a key 'primary_key' and value should be the primary key of the table. then you need to make sure you have a value in your form whose name matches that primary key. so if you're editing a model Page whose Id i 3, you need <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3">. lastly i also put the primary_key column in my form as well, so $this->setValidator('id', new sfValidatorString(array('required'=> true))). all in all,  changes to 3 files got the job done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The update situation is indeed handled by sfValidatorDoctrineUnique.

In your case if object with given URL already exists validator will check if you're performing an update operation. Check is made with *sfValidatorDoctrineUnique::isUpdate()* method.

**Your primary key(s) need to be in the submitted values.**

By default primary key is introspected. You can provide it with *primary_key* option passed to the validator.

Comment: thanks, sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. Would you be able to provide a quick example of how to use it? Not well documented, it seems.

Comment: .... no worries, figured out. Thought initially that I'd need to call that method. Thanks for your help.

Comment: hi kuba,
can you please explain how to use sfValidatorDoctrineUnique::isUpdate() or a example of sfValidatorDoctrineUnique with primary_key option

Comment: @ShashankPatel [I know this is waaaaaay late, but] see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

As noted in other answers, it is important to make sure of the following:

- The PK value for the updated object must be present in the submitted form values.
- The `sfValidatorDoctrineUnique` validator must be aware of *all* values submitted with the form.

In order to accomplish this, you must perform the following steps:

1. Add a hidden input that contains (usually) the PK value for your object:

   ```
   class MyModelForm extends BaseMyModelForm
   {
     public function configure(  )
     {
       if( ! $this->isNew() )
       {
         $this->widgetSchema['id']    = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden();
         $this->validatorSchema['id'] = new sfValidatorNumber(array(
             'required' => true
           , 'min'      => 1
         ));
       }

       ...
     }

     ...
   }
   ```

   - Note that this extra input only needs to be added if you are updating.
2. Move the `sfValidatorDoctrineUnique` to the post-validation phase:

   ```
   class MyModelForm extends BaseMyModelForm
   {
     public function configure(  )
     {
       $this->widgetSchema['unique_column']    = new sfWidgetFormInputText();
       $this->validatorSchema['unique_column'] = new sfValidatorPass();

       ...

       $this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array(
           'required' => true
         , 'model'    => 'MyModel'
         , 'column'   => 'unique_column'
       )));
     }

     ...
   }
   ```

   - You will need to use `$this->mergePostValidator()` to add the validator to the post-validation phase so that *all* submitted values are provided to the validator.
   - Note that you still need to supply a validator for the unique column widget, or else you will get an "Unexpected extra form field" error when you submit the form.
3. Ensure that you are passing the object being updated to the constructor of your form:

   ```
   $this->form = new MyModelForm($this->getRoute()->getObject());
   ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Couldn't find this anywhere in the docs and I was going crazy looking at the isUpdate source and realizing that it would always fail because it wasn't getting the PK values.

Comment: May seems obvious but be sure primary key widget is not unset in the model form class (like when using `unsetAllExcept()` method)